# Заполнение колонки на основе соседней

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Подскажите пожалуйста, по решению вопроса.
У меня есть колонка STATE (boolean), добавил колонку NAME (varchar).
Необходимо заполнить NAME на основании содержания STATE.
Чтобы получился вот такой результат.
[image: mysql table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно вот так:

```
UPDATE _tableName
SET NAME = IF(STATE = True, 'STATE_1', 'STATE_0')
```